# error regarding test deployment using yarn hardhat

Tags: blockchain, solidity, hardhat

MedicalRecords
Deployment
1) The contract is deployed successfully

0 passing (2s)
1 failing

1. MedicalRecords
   Deployment
   The contract is deployed successfully:
   TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="address", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.4.0)
   at makeError (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:656:21)
   at assert (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:680:25)
   at assertArgument (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:692:5)
   at Interface.getFunctionName (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\interface.ts:416:23)
   at buildWrappedMethod (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:334:34)
   at BaseContract.getFunction (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:783:22)
   at Object.get (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:714:39)
   at Context. (test\MedicalRecords.test.js:13:28)

please help me to solve his problem

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for the particular issue.

That is:

```
expect(await medical.getAddress()).to.not.equal(0);
```

Use it instead of:

```
expect(await medical.address()).to.not.equal(0);
```